# Excel vba web scraping: how to hide chrome browser while code execution

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, web, screen-scraping

i wanted to ask if using Chrome o Edge and Selenium with Excel vba (web scraping) i can not show the browser as you can do with Internet.Explorer *IE.Visible = False*
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, accurate better

With Interenet Explorer

```
Set IE = createobject (InternetExplorer.Application)
With IE
     .Visible = False
     .Navigate URL
End With
```

With Chrome and Selenium ?

```
  Dim driver As New WebDriver
     With driver
          **.Visible = False ????**
         .Start "Chrome", ""
         .Get URL
  End With
```